# Prompt Message not coming in IE11 form by using simple_form - rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, prompt

I am unable to get prompt in IE11 'Please select an item in the list' message when the form is submitted. Though it's not submitting the form, the message is not coming. I am able to get in IE 13, safari, firefox and chrome. It's a specific requirement. Is there anyway to get that done?

Rails version: 4.0.6
simple_form: 3.0.2

`= simple_form_for(:report, url: report_create_path, method: :get, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
   = f.simple_fields_for(:q) do |r|
     = r.input :search, label: 'Search By', required: true, collection: [['Policy', 'policy'], ['Region / Booth Code', 'code']], input_html: { class: 'search-performance' }
   footer
     = f.submit 'Generate', class: 'btn btn-primary'`

I need to get a popup message like in image, showing the sample of firefox

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused are you referring to, is this a JavaScript prompt or perhaps a tool tip? Its difficult for people to help you without seeing any code. Can you reproduce the issue in a [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or perhaps paste your relevant code?